# Instagram API access token refresh?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, instagram-api, refresh-token

I'm not sure if this is just exclusive to google API's and this is not plausible, but in the OAuth google developers playground, one can give in an access token and receive a refresh token which never expires. I for one have done this and implemented it in my code, but I was wondering, is there such a thing for an Instagram access token?

With the recent changes taking place in there api (2016 ->), I have not found any questions asking this as before I believe the token did not expire.

Thank you and sorry if I seem to be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [doc](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

> Access tokens may expire at any time in the future.

> Even though our access tokens do not specify an expiration time, your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access, or Instagram expires the token after some period of time.

So in short, today, tokens do not expire, but they could in the future, so your app must handle the case if one day they expire.

Comment: Oh ok - sorry, I guess I had read that as they can, in the sense of just as much as they can't, expire anytime in the future - still, out of curiosity, could there be anyway to get a refresh token like you can with Google's API's?